# Does new / malloc cause memory shuffling in the environment of sufficient but fragmented memory?

Tags: c++, c, memory, memory-management, out-of-memory

This is just out of curiousity.

For example, let's say we have used up 2 of 8 bytes of memory:

```
[xx------]
```

If I call new / malloc requesting for 3 bytes, it should work just fine, perhaps like so:

```
[xx--xxx-]
```

What then happens if I call new / malloc requesting for another 3 bytes? In terms of available memory, there are still 3 free bytes, even though they are not contiguous. Will the program then "defragment" memory to make space for the new allocation? Sounds impossible as I would still be holding on to references to the existing allocs.

If so, then by extension to an extreme case, if your memory ***somehow*** ends up super fragmented (eg every other byte is allocated ala `[x-x-x-x- x-x-x-x-]`), does that mean I cannot allocate even 2 bytes despite having 50% memory free?

I don't suppose the platform matters?

Sorry for the extended question, but would this also happen in other languages like Java/C#?

Comment: This is heavily architecture dependant i think.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox: most systems if not all have a flat (virtual) addressing space. The heap blocks are allocated contiguously and accessed via a simple pointer, so that pointer arithmetic is straightforward. This causes the fragmentation issue.

Comment: Yes for C/C++. sometimes malloc uses sbrk other times it uses mmap. In all cases it can not move data as that would invalidate the pointers your program is using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's right, the memory can get so fragmented that no allocations are possible anymore. A good allocator will merge the released blocks when possible, to limit fragmentation.

The MS .NET managed framework solves this problem by allocating the memory blocks indirectly, i.e. via a pointer to a pointer to a block. This way, a block can be moved to defragment memory, without changing the pointer to the pointer. (Some care is taken by the framework to avoid concurrency problems, because .NET has a garbage collector running asynchronously.)

Comment: The MS .net framework does not solve the fragmentation issue inherent to using `malloc()`, it just offers an alternative way of handling memory blocks with very specific constraints and some advantages.

Comment: @chqrlie: I was speaking of gcnew, of course. It does defragment, otherwise the double reference would be of no use.